# Copying the Last Successful Artifacts from Any Branch in Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, branch

I'd like to copy an artifact in my pipeline for a project, regardless of the branch. As long as the last job is successful, I'd like to get that artifact from the last branch that had a successful job.

Is it even possible?

Currently it works well using `projectName: env.JOB_NAME` but that only uses the same branch.

If I use the service name like below, it is giving me an error:

```
copyArtifacts(
  filter: '**/myFile',
  fingerprintArtifacts: true,
  projectName: 'folderName/' + env.SERVICE_NAME,
  optional: true
)
```

the exception returned:

```
ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: <folderName>/<serviceName>
```

Also, if this is possible at all, do I have to change anything in the way I upload my artifacts, for example using `archiveArtifacts`?

Thanks!